# Antonym for 'replicable'

Tags: antonyms

After a far greater than anticipated amount of research, I am still unable to find and confirm an exact antonym for the word 'replicable'.  I have found multiple sites that have one (or some combination) of the three following words: 'unreplicable', 'non-replicable', and 'irreplicable'.  For a 4 page paper that I am writing, (I'll be using one of these three words in a thesis statement which I've been attempting to perfect for 20 minutes now), which one of these three words (or maybe some other word) would be best?

My thesis statement is here: https://pastebin.com/7ywaPhq3

Comment: With ***once-in-a-lifetime*** emotion...

Comment: I'd be inclined to use "irreplicable".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though none of the reliable dictionaries includes words *irreplicable, unreplicable, and non-replicable/nonreplicable*, they are seen on websites  as normal as any other words. Of these three words, the non-hyphenated *nonreplicable* has the highest acceptability and *unreplicable* is more acceptable than *irreplicable* as per the Google Ngram Viewer.

[image]

I think it is better to avoid any such dubious words in an academic thesis and instead, rephrase the sentence using some other expressions, as:

**...while managing to invigorate nearly all viewers with *[irreproducible](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/irreproducible)* emotions**.

Comment: But isn’t each viewer “reproducing” that emotion? 8^p

Answer (score 0):

Replicable means something for which a replica (a copy) can be created.

**Reproducible** means something that can be reproduced.

A replica is considered to be a more exact duplicate than a reproduction, but the terms "replicable" and "reproducible" are similar in meaning.

Answer (score -1):

Would *unrepeatable* be an option?

> *invigorate nearly all viewers with **unrepeatable** emotion.*

I might even go so far as to say

> *invigorate nearly all viewers with **unique and unrepeatable** emotion.*

Also, you might want to consider removing the comma before while:

> *...maintaining much significance itself while managing...*